# How can we ensure a unique identifier to each and every UI element so that my QA team can catch any DOM element while automation testing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, automation

So my testing team require the unique identifier for each DOM element for their automation testing. Ideally with the help of Xpath we can achieve this, but in my application we have scenarios we a user can change the positions of the elements. (For eg: There is list of 5 items and a user can move the 3rd item to 1st by dragging and which is why the Xpath fails). Hence looking for the pluggin or something due to which I can apply unique identifier on each DOM element to my current running application.

Comment: I think this will be good enough:
new Date().getTime() + Math.random();

Comment: Are you talking about EVERY element, or just a select few?  What tools do you currently use - I assume this isn't hand-coded?

Comment: Mike - We are using selenium and QA team requires it for EVERY element. 
Almog - Buddy this will again give me some random value every-time on rendering and my QA team needs some fixed value so that once they create XPath will work everytime it renders.